# jquery to check if h1 from another page have the word "stock"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling a little bit to read H1 from another page. The H1 from the page I need to read is dynamic, and I need to check if it have a specific word, something like:

> if h1 have the word "stock", run 'js/stock.js' else if h1 have the
>   word "formula", run 'js/formula.js', else if h1 have the word "tour",
>   run 'js/tour.js'.

I could only find codes about LOADING the content from the other page h1 to my page, but not reading.

HTML code from the page I need to read:

```
<h1 id="Title"><img src="http://www.ntcrono.com/nt/Images/_Stop.png">Camp. Bras. Stock Car - 2ª Bateria<img src="http://www.ntcrono.com/nt/Images/_Stop.png"></h1>
<p id="Time"><span id="DayTime">26/4/2015 14:49:40</span><span id="ElapsedTime">00:34:42</span><span id="RemainingTime">0 Lp., </span></p>

<table width="100%">
<tr class="HeaderRow">
<td id="Id_Position" align="left" width="25">P</td>
<td id="Id_Numero" align="left" width="25">No.</td>
<td id="Id_Perso1" align="left" width="80">Driver</td>
<td id="Id_Equipe" align="left" width="190">Team</td>
<td id="Id_Vehicule" align="left" width="60">Model</td>
<td id="Id_NbTour" align="left" width="25">L</td>
<td id="Id_TpsCumule" align="left" width="85">Total time</td>
<td id="Id_VitesseMoyTotal" align="left" width="30">Avg</td>
<td id="Id_Ecart1er" align="left" width="35">Gap</td>
<td id="Id_EcartPrec" align="left" width="50">PGap</td>
<td id="Id_MeilleurTour" align="left" width="50">Best</td>
<td id="Id_AuTour" align="left" width="25">In</td>
<td id="Id_Inter1" align="left" width="45">S1</td>
<td id="Id_MeilleurInter1" align="left" width="45">BS1</td>
<td id="Id_Inter2" align="left" width="45">S2</td>
<td id="Id_MeilleurInter2" align="left" width="45">BS2</td>
<td id="Id_Inter3" align="left" width="45">S3</td>
<td id="Id_MeilleurInter3" align="left" width="45">BS3</td>
<td id="Id_TpsTour" align="left" width="50">Laptime</td>
<td id="Id_NbStand" align="left" width="20">P</td>
<td id="Id_PositionDepart" align="left" width="20">StartP</td>
</tr>
<tr class="OddRow">
<td align="left" class="">1</td>
<td align="left" class="">65</td>
<td align="left" class="">MAX</td>
<td align="left" class="">Eurofarma RC</td>
<td align="left" class="">Chevrolet</td>
<td align="left" class="">26</td>
<td align="left" class="">00:28:06.567</td>
<td align="left" class="">126.42</td>
<td align="left" class="">-</td>
<td align="left" class="">-</td>
<td align="left" class="">55.487</td>
<td align="left" class="">23</td>
<td align="left" class="BestTime">15.572</td>
<td align="left" class="">15.572</td>
<td align="left" class="">-</td>
<td align="left" class="">16.086</td>
<td align="left" class="">21:55.535</td>
<td align="left" class="">24.066</td>
<td align="left" class="">56.208</td>
<td align="left" class="">0</td>
<td align="left" class="">1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="EvenRow">
<td align="left" class="">2</td>
<td align="left" class="">0</td>
<td align="left" class="">CBU</td>
<td align="left" class="">Red Bull Racing</td>
<td align="left" class="">Chevrolet</td>
<td align="left" class="">26</td>
<td align="left" class="">00:28:07.910</td>
<td align="left" class="">126.32</td>
<td align="left" class="">1.343</td>
<td align="left" class="">1.343</td>
<td align="left" class="">55.590</td>
<td align="left" class="">10</td>
<td align="left" class="">15.977</td>
<td align="left" class="">15.711</td>
<td align="left" class="">-</td>
<td align="left" class="">16.126</td>
<td align="left" class="">6:57.520</td>
<td align="left" class="">24.183</td>
<td align="left" class="">56.293</td>
<td align="left" class="">0</td>
<td align="left" class="">6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `$.get()` instead of `$.load()`. The callback will receive the HTML as a parameter.

Comment: Is the other page in the same domain as your page? You won't be able to access its content if it isn't.

Comment: Hey Michael, yes, it's in the same domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.get` to get the contents of the other site into a variable. Then parse it and check the contents of the `<h1>`:

```
$.get(otherSiteUrl, function(data) {
    var dom = $('<div>', {html: data }); // parse the HTML
    var h1Text = dom.find("h1").text();
    if (h1Text.indexOf("Stock") != -1) {
        $.getScript("js/stock.js");
    } else if (h1Text.indexOf("Formula") != -1) {
        $.getScript("js/formula.js");
    } else if (h1Text.indexOf("Tour") != -1) {
        $.getScript("js/tour.js");
    }
}, "html");
```

Comment: I'm trying this one to test, but it doesn't run the console.log(). Am I doing something wrong? `$.get('p1.html', function(data) {
   var dom = $(data); // parse the HTML
   switch(dom.find("h1").text()) {
    case "Stock": 
     console.log("Stock");
     break;
   }
  }, "html");`

Comment: Does it contain `stock` or `Stock`? Can you add the actual HTML of `p1.html` to your question?

Comment: It's `Stock`. Sure, I just edited the question with the code.

Comment: My code only works if the only text in the `<h1>` is the word `Stock`. I didn't know it had to be a substring search. I'll update.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that. I'm now getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: h1 is not defined` on console. What could it be?

Comment: `h1.text` was a typo for `h1Text`

Comment: Maaan...worked like a charm! Can't thank you enough for this :DDDD